# pair wise melt in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I want to pair wise create a new dataframe. I tried using MELT but it did not really work. 
If you notice columns are pair wise ( i.e code:type , code1:type1 ) 
I tried creating a list of code columns and list of type columns and then do melt.

How would you suggest this issue? I would appreciate if some explanation is given.

ORIGINAL DATAFRAME:

```
id   Name  code code1 code2  type type1 type2
 0    ABC    1      4     8   S     E      T
 1    XYZ    2            5   R            U
```

EXPECTED DATAFRAME

```
id name  Code_All Type_All
0   ABC      1      S
0   ABC      4      E
0   ABC      8      T
1   XYZ      2      R
1   XYZ               
1   XYZ      5      U
```

Comment: look at `pd.wide_to_long`

Comment: could you please guide in the case of 'paired' columns. can i do in a single line code or should it be in a loop?

Comment: does column `code 2` has a space as shown? or is it a typo and should be `code2` ?

Comment: hi @anky_91 yes it was a typo. Your response would be appericiated.

Comment: @anky_91 I tried
df.set_index(['ID','Name']).stack().reset_index()
which gives me 
but I need to have single column for code columns and separate column for type columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few frustrating hours, I was able to complete this using a dirty trick.

I split the dataset in two.

`id, name, code1, code2, code3`

`id, name, type1, type2, type3`

I transposed the two dataframes

Example of first dataframe.

`id, name, code1`

`id, name, code2`

`id, name, code3`

Using the pd.concat([df1.df2], axix=1)
I was able to concatenate it and removed NULL values and duplicate column names

FINAL DATAFRAME

`id, name, code1, type1`

`id, name, code2, type2`

`id, name, code3, type3`

Answer (score 0):

Here problem is we don't have a clear suffix (first entry for every group is without a suffix) for [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) , hence modified the columns first and then applied `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
m  = df.set_index(['id','Name'])
cols = m.columns.str.replace('\d+','').to_series()
m.columns=cols.add(cols.groupby(cols).cumcount().astype(str))

out = (pd.wide_to_long(m.reset_index(),['code','type'],['id','Name'],'idx')
                                              .reset_index(['id','Name']))
```

---

```
     id Name  code type
idx                    
0     0  ABC   1.0    S
1     0  ABC   4.0    E
2     0  ABC   8.0    T
0     1  XYZ   2.0    R
1     1  XYZ   NaN  NaN
2     1  XYZ   5.0    U
```

Code to reproduce the dataframe:

```
d = {'id': {0: 0, 1: 1},
  'Name': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'XYZ'},
  'code': {0: 1, 1: 2},
  'code1': {0: 4.0, 1: np.nan},
  'code2': {0: 8, 1: 5},
  'type': {0: 'S', 1: 'R'},
  'type1': {0: 'E', 1: np.nan},
  'type2': {0: 'T', 1: 'U'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: I am unable to understand the logic about the name of columns and how you are separating it. 
The original columns are  ID, Name, Attributes.ProducerCode.ProducerCode, Attributes.ProducerCode1.ProducerCode, Attributes.ProducerCode2.ProducerCode, Attributes.ProducerPartyRole.ProducerPartyRoleType, Attributes.ProducerPartyRole2.ProducerPartyRoleType, Attributes.ProducerPartyRole3.ProducerPartyRoleType.

Comment: Btw, thank you so much for your patience. You are saving my butt at work!  ( deadlines argh ! )

Comment: For wide to long to work, we would need the suffixes as numeric in an increasing manner, check how the column of m are before the wide to long line

Comment: Hi, I tried ! no output. Check my picture, sorry cant take snippet. tinyurl.com/widelongso 
as you can see I renamed the columns too !